# How use jQuery UI from jQuery Update in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drupal

this is my first question here so I hope I'll do it properly :).

I recently begin to use Drupal and for the jQuery I'm using the module "jQuery Update". That work perfectly but now I also want to use jQuery UI but it seems to not be recognized, even on simply things like

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<script>
     $(function() {
         $("#slider").slider();
     });
</script>
```

I wondered if maybe I have to do something first before I can use jQuery UI. Otherwise I really don't know how solve my problem.

So if you have a solution please answer me, thank you :D.

Answer (score 0):

AfAIK, you must use jQuery instead of $ in drupal. you can find more details on https://drupal.org/node/171213

refering to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18443/using-drupal-7-built-in-jquery-ui-in-my-theme) you also can add jQuery UI using [system libraries](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_library/7) and your theme's preprocess_page hook. like :

```
function NAME_OF_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'effects.highlight');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but even with jQuery instead of $, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I already try this but this isn't working either. Plus, I'm trying to use jQuery UI with the module 'jQuery Update' but your solution has nothing to do with it.

Comment: system library ui is jQuery UI core. jQuery Update module alters this behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 0):

abyz's answer is correct, but you can also attach jQuery autocomplete in this way:

```
$content['#attached']['library'][] =  array('system', 'ui');
$content['#attached']['library'][] =  array('system', 'ui.autocomplete');
```

see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102914/attaching-a-system-js-library-using-attached-property-d7